# How can I get the strings contained in tag in the XML code?

Tags: java, android

How can I get the values surrounded in red?

[image]

Comment: two steps: 1.parse xml 2. retrieve value from object representation

Comment: @JakubDóka Please, can you show me the code?

Comment: do some research on related steps i recommended and then if you cannot figure it out tell me

Comment: @JakubDóka I did some research, but I confess I don't understand anything

Answer (score 0):

You can get your view's tags programmatically like this;

```
String myTag = findViewById(R.id.card_resultat_1).getTag();
```

Comment: When I do this code in a Dialog fragment the application crashes:
```String myTag = (String) view.findViewById(R.id.card_result_1).getTag();
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "SUpper: " + myTag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();```

Comment: Make sure you can get your view reference correctly. I wrote this as an example. When you get your view, then you can use yourView.getTag() wherever you want to get those "tag values" defined in xml (or programmatically). If you can share the error trace we might be able to help you further.

Comment: i get this error: ` java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.view.View.getTag()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Yes it seems your view reference is null. That's why you are getting this error. Make sure you have your tagged view with id "R.id.card_result_1" in the scope. If you don't have a reference to your view from dialog; you can also get the tag value from your activity and then pass this string as an argumant to your dialog.